# Using FFI to Attach_function to a C Function with variable argument lists?

Tags: ruby, ffi

Simple case, something like printf(str, [arg1, arg2, ...])

How would I write a ruby 'attach_function' call using FFI to utilize such a function?

I'm surprised that I can't find this question answered through my googling, but perhaps I'm using the wrong terminology.

-- update -- 
Perhaps I was not clear enough.  I am already in the middle of writing a RubyGem that interfaces with a C library.  Its working just fine already.  I'm using FFI and was going along just fine until I hit this function with a variable argument list.

Answer (score 2):

The canonical way to use a C function in ruby is to extend ruby through creating a gem for it. There is no straight forward method like Haskell has.

However, writing a C gem for ruby is a fairly easy task, almost as easy as use a FFI in Haskell. You can see [this free chapter from ruby pickaxe](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/ext_ruby.html) that teaches how to create a simple C gem, and should be enough to get going.

**edit**

If your problem is with varargs and ffi, assuming you are using the `ffi gem`, you can look [the examples on documentation](https://github.com/ffi/ffi/wiki/Examples), where this example shows how to do it:

```
require 'ffi'

module Hello
  extend FFI::Library
  attach_function 'printf', [:string, :varargs], :int
end

3.times {  Hello.printf("cputs %s %d %x", :string, "yoyo", :int, 33, :int, 34)} # each one needs its own specifier of which type it is
```

If you try this and didn't work, let us see your code and tell us what went wrong

Comment: I specifically mentioned FFI for Ruby.

Comment: @BadQuanta My bad, fixed the answer. However, if you are already writing a gem, will answer only your curiosity.

Comment: Thank you so much, this was the answer I needed.  I kept googling for "FFI Ruby Variable Arguments" and completely overlooked that section of the docs.

Comment: @BadQuanta Happy to help. As odd as it seems, these functions are called `variadic` or simply `varargs` - this might help you in your next googles.

Comment: This example code did not work here. There is an error: `LoadError: no library specified`

However, I just included the default C library via `ffi_lib 'c'` inside the `Hello` module and, after that, the code worked fine here. Very good.